# message to appear using onFocus in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

I have created a form, when I click on a text field I want a message to appear below the form using onFocus.

```
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="john" />
```

So when clicked on that field I would like a message that says 'this is where you enter your name'

I tried

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("fname") 'dont know what to put here'
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="john" onfocus="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("fname").value = "your message";

Comment: you could also use css only for this one through :focus pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

You could use css for this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="john" />
<span>your text</span>


span {
display:none;
}
input:focus + span {
display:block;
}
```

here is the javascript solution:

```
var span = document.querySelector("span");
var input = document.querySelector("#fname")

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
span.innerHTML = "your text";
});
```